# Get URL to website from within Application_Start?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes

**Hi,**

I need to generate a correct URL to a action in my APS.NET MVC 3 website and this have to be done in the Application_Start in Gloabl.asax.

I have tried to set a UrlHelper but the HttpContext.Current is always null?

The adress i look for is somthing like this : http://www.mysite.se/MyController/MyAction.

I have also tried VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/") but that will only give me "/mysite/"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't access the `HttpContext` in the `Application_Start` when the application is running in the IIS integration mode (you can achieve that in the classic mode but that's not recommended).

Mike describes [here](http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart) a workaround how to do that in `Application_BeginRequest` such that your code still runs only for the first request not for the later ones.