# Getting website's root URL from Global.asax.Application_Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there any way to get my website's root URL (for instance https://MyWebDomain.com:443/MyWebAppRoot) from within the Application_Start handler, i.e. without access to Page or HttpContext.Current.Request objects?

Comment: Your site could be bound to multiple different bindings. So as far as I'm aware, there's not a way to get it without having an HttpContext. One thing you can do is put the root URL into your configuration file (such as appSettings) and then read it from there in Application_Start.

Comment: This link will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458567/get-url-to-website-from-within-application-start