# Find website URL in RegisterBundles from BundleConfig

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a website where a css file is loaded from the BundleConfig:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
     bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
     "~/Content/BootStrapTheme.css", 
     "~/Content/site.css", 
}
```

However, this application is going to be multi-tenant which would each require their own separate css file to be loaded.

In any of my Controllers, I can easily find the url by writing something on the lines of:

```
var getHostName = Request.Url.Host;
```

This would return 'localhost'  since I'm dubugging or the domain name in live (i.e. 'stackoverflow').

I am trying to perform a check using the above line in the RegisterBundles of bundleConfig file such as:

```
if(getHostName == "Website1")
{ 
    //Load css file No.1 
}
else 
{ 
    //Load css file No.2 
}
```

Is this possible?

I have tried various ways of finding the Url but to no avail. Anything which I try elsewhere (i.e. in my Controllers) works, but fail when in the BundleConfig.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you already tried to call `HttpContext.Current.Request` in the BundleConfig?

Comment: You won't be able to do that in the application start method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458567/get-url-to-website-from-within-application-start

Comment: However, you could add your website name to your config file during deployment, that way you would still know the correct URL or you add your bundles on Application_BeginRequest only once